# Variable value isn't changing according to checkbox value from rtf theme

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Preparing a bootstrap application to install some msi packages. Have option to choose the packages to install. But the variable value is not changing as per the user selection. 
 This is how I use variable in my `Bundle.wxs` file

```
<Variable Name="spectrumDb" Persisted="yes"  bal:Overridable="yes"  Value="1"  />
<Variable Name="spectrumGateway" Persisted="yes"  bal:Overridable="yes"  Value="1" />
<Variable Name="spectrumServiceManager" Persisted="yes"  bal:Overridable="yes" Value="1" />
<Variable Name="spectrumIISparts" Persisted="yes"  bal:Overridable="yes" Value="1"  />
<Variable Name="spectrumConnecter" Persisted="yes"  bal:Overridable="yes"  Value="1" />
```

I have some checkboxes in rtf theme for the user to select components to install

```
<Page Name="Options">      
     <Text X="11" Y="65" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">Select components</Text>
     <Checkbox Name="spectrumDb" X="40" Y="120" Width="200" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="no"   >spectrumDb</Checkbox>
     <Checkbox Name="spectrumGateway" X="40" Y="140" Width="200" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="no">spectrumGateway</Checkbox>
     <Checkbox Name="spectrumServiceManager" X="40" Y="160" Width="200" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="no" >spectrumServiceManager</Checkbox>
     <Checkbox Name="spectrumIISparts" X="40" Y="180" Width="200" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="no" >spectrumIISparts</Checkbox>
     <Checkbox Name="spectrumConnecter" X="40" Y="200" Width="200" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="no" >spectrumConnecter</Checkbox>
</Page>
```

The installer install irrespective of the checkbox value. This is the part of logfile where I find that

```
[0404:0B44][2018-05-28T08:43:07]i000: Running detect complete custom action
[0404:0B44][2018-05-28T08:43:07]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0404:178C][2018-05-28T08:43:09]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[0404:178C][2018-05-28T08:43:20]i000: Setting numeric variable 'spectrumDb' to value 1
[0404:178C][2018-05-28T08:43:20]i000: Setting numeric variable 'spectrumGateway' to value 1
[0404:178C][2018-05-28T08:43:20]i000: Setting numeric variable 'spectrumServiceManager' to value 1
[0404:178C][2018-05-28T08:43:20]i000: Setting numeric variable 'spectrumIISparts' to value 1
[0404:178C][2018-05-28T08:43:20]i000: Setting numeric variable 'spectrumConnecter' to value 1
```

I use wix 3.11 to make this project. 
ide is visual studio 2010. 
bootstrap application type ref WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrapper will set the variable when it runs this function:

```
void SavePageSettings(
    __in WIXSTDBA_PAGE page
    )
{
    THEME_PAGE* pPage = NULL;

    pPage = ThemeGetPage(m_pTheme, m_rgdwPageIds[page]);
    if (pPage)
    {
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < pPage->cControlIndices; ++i)
        {
            // Loop through all the checkbox controls (or buttons with BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON) with names and set a Burn variable with that name to true or false.
            THEME_CONTROL* pControl = m_pTheme->rgControls + pPage->rgdwControlIndices[i];
            if ((THEME_CONTROL_TYPE_CHECKBOX == pControl->type) ||
                (THEME_CONTROL_TYPE_BUTTON == pControl->type && (BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON == (BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON & pControl->dwStyle)) &&
                pControl->sczName && *pControl->sczName))
            {
                BOOL bChecked = ThemeIsControlChecked(m_pTheme, pControl->wId);
                m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(pControl->sczName, bChecked ? 1 : 0);
            }

            // Loop through all the editbox controls with names and set a Burn variable with that name to the contents.
            if (THEME_CONTROL_TYPE_EDITBOX == pControl->type && pControl->sczName && *pControl->sczName && WIXSTDBA_CONTROL_FOLDER_EDITBOX != pControl->wId)
            {
                LPWSTR sczValue = NULL;
                ThemeGetTextControl(m_pTheme, pControl->wId, &sczValue);
                m_pEngine->SetVariableString(pControl->sczName, sczValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `SetVariableNumeric` function won't log anything for an already existing variable.

You can verify your variables are being set by running your bootstrapper, unchecking a few check boxes, going to the next page, and then cancelling your bootstrapper.

When you close the bootstrapper it logs all variables and their values. In the logs after you close the bootstrapper, you should see that the variables corresponding to the checkboxes you unchecked should now have a value of 0.

Comment: I could figure out what the issue(but not sure). bal:Overridable="yes" is not working.When I set variable value to 0, that reflects in checkbox. but reverse isn't happen. Is that a 'oneway' thing???

Comment: @Arvin You should not need `bal:Overridable='yes'` at all. That just indicates you can override the initial value from the command line.

Comment: Can you run your bootstrapper, change the state of a checkbox, **go to a new page**, then cancel your bootstrapper and verify the value of the variable corresponding to that checkbox has changed in the final log of the bootstrapper logs where it lists all variables and their values? I think you are just expecting to see a log line saying the variable value changed but you will not see that log line since it doesn't get logged for already existing variables.

Comment: So at the end of your bootstrapper logs after you open the bootstrapper, uncheck the spectrumDb checkbox and click next or install or back (just to trigger the save page settings code) then cancel your bootstrapper and close the bootstrapper, do you see after the "Shutting down, exit code: 0x642": `...Variable: spectrumDb  = 0` along with other variable log lines or is it `= 1`?